# How to use ngIf to choose diffrent selector in html in an angular app

Tags: html, angular, angular-ng-if

I have a question about how to use ngIF in HTML code to choose different selector.

I show my code as follow:

```
in HTML Code:

<a class="style" (click)=clickFunction() (keyup.Enter)=ke()>
  <div>
    content

  </div>
</a>
```

this is html is in a shared component,

I want to use this shared component into the other component with input parameter noClickAndKeyEnter=true |false

so in this case I should change html code as follow:

```
<a class="stype" (click)="noClickAndKeyEnter ? clickFunction(): ''" (keyup.Enter)="noClickAndKeyEnter ? ke() :''">
  <div>
    content

  </div>
</a>
```

My question is, is there also the easy way to resolve my question, that I do not write all place with  noClickAndKeyEnter ? :

any solutions?

Comment: Instead of ternary operator you can use && conditional operator (click)="noClickAndKeyEnter && clickFunction()"

Answer (score 0):

You can use the callback pattern!

ts

```
conditionallyExecute(callback: Function, ...params) {
    if(this.noClickAndKeyEnter) {
        callback(params)
    }
}
```

html

```
<a class="stype" (click)="conditionallyExecute(clickFunction, 1, 2)" (keyup.Enter)="conditionallyExecute(ke)">
  <div>
    content

  </div>
</a>
```

Comment: I have a qeustion how about with parameter in clickfuction?

Comment: such as conditionallyExecute(clickFunction(parameter, parameter2)) ???

Comment: I have get error message, because a parameter is $event.

Comment: a mouse event or a keyboard event

Comment: @user1938143 `(click)="conditionallyExecute(clickFunction, $event)"`

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways you can do this. The simplest could be:

```
 clickFunction(){
    if(this.noClickAndKeyEnter){
      // execute code here
    } else {
      // just return or whatever you want here
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a simple guard in your functions

```js
clickFunction() {
    if (!this.noClickAndKeyEnter) return;
    ...
}

ke() {
    if (!this.noClickAndKeyEnter) return;
    ...
}
```

But by the name of `noClickAndKeyEnter` I think you might have the true / false values backwards.